# Login Validation For HTML Theme

Tags: javascript, html

I recently mirrored a login Html Template. I want a user who enters a specific username and password to be redirected to another page and any other login detail entered get an error alert. Could you kindly help me out?

Find the code below:

```html
<h3>Sign into your account</h3>
<form action="index-bank-2.html" method="GET">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="input-text" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" name="Password" class="input-text" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox clearfix">
    <div class="form-check checkbox-theme">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="rememberMe">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="rememberMe">
                                        Remember me
                                    </label>
    </div>
    <a href="forgot-password-1.html">Forgot Password</a>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-0">
    <button type="submit" class="btn-md btn-theme btn-block">Login</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: So, where's the code to handle the redirect?

Comment: <script language="javascript">
            function check(form) { 
                if(form.email.value == "myuserid@gmail.com" && form.Password.value == "mypswrd") {
                    window.open('index.html')
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error Password or Username")
                }
            }
        </script>

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question by editing it, not to the comment section - additionally, what's the need of using a password when you put it to the page in plain text?

Answer (score 0):

`<form action="index-bank-2.html" method="GET">`

is wrong..you need PHP or any back-end language to validate your login credentials. You may try like this

`<form action="validate_user.php" method="POST">`

Create validate_user.php file and you need POST method instead of GET because you are sending data over HTTP and GET request(read up on HTTP request)  only used to retrieve data.

Quick google by me: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php

You may refer above link to implement what you are looking for. Good luck!